# Failed to find configured root error in android 7.0

Tags: android

I get this error: `failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/android/data/` 
There are some similar questions but they are using other location for storing files.
I am using:
   `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`  method and this is the code I'm using to open camera:

```
 private void TakePicture() {
    photoFile = FileManager.generateFileStampedPhotoFile();
    PicturesHelper.TryTakePictureWithAnIntent(this, photoFile, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}


public static File generateFileStampedPhotoFile()
{
    Uri photoFileUri=null;
    File photoFile=null;
    File outputDir=getPhotoDirectory();
    if(outputDir!=null)
    {
        String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDD_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String photoFileName="IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg";
         photoFile=new File(outputDir,photoFileName);
       // photoFileUri=Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

    }
    return  photoFile;
}


 public static void TryTakePictureWithAnIntent(Activity context,File 
   photoFile,int requestCode)
  {
    Intent takePictureIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())!=null) //if user has camera?
    {

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    "com.myapp.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

            context.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
        }

    }
}


public static File getPhotoDirectory()
{
    File outputDir=null;
    String externalStorageState=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File pictureDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        outputDir=new File(new File(pictureDir,"Adriagate"),"Online");
        if(!outputDir.exists())//V.P. if directory/ies not exist/s it will be created. mksdrs method follows file structure and creates directory by direcory if needed
        {
            if(!outputDir.mkdirs())
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return outputDir;
}
```

I have put provider inside AndroidManifest:

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And this is file_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files name="Whatever_Nothing_Works"/>
```

Comment: can you please show the Android Menifest file

Comment: It is shown now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your images in `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. That is not one of the supported roots for `FileProvider`. Plus, your XML has `<external-files>`, and that is not a supported element for `FileProvider` (valid ones all end in `-path`).

Options include:

- Changing the location of where you are storing the images to one of the locations supported by `FileProvider` and adjusting your XML to match
- Switching to [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) and using `<external-public-path dir="Pictures">`
- Changing your XML to `<external-path name="whatever" path="Pictures">` and hope for the best

Comment: FileProvider works. It seems I had to clean project. Then I got another error (related to permissions). After I resolved that now I can take pictures. This is xml that works: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

Comment: @Vlado: Note that your XML configuration will serve anything in external storage, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: I want that uploading of pictures works as before :) I hope it will works on all earlier versions of android as well. I have to check that now.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in Menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Replace in file_paths.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
       <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Your file is stored under getExternalFilesDir(). That maps to `<external-files-path>`, not `<files-path>`

Comment: "Your file is stored under getExternalFilesDir()" -- not according to the code in the question.